# Delete child entity when removed from parent collection in one to many relationship Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following database setup:
[image]

The tables are mapped as follow:

```
public class OrderMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
{
    public OrderMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Orders", "prf");

        this.HasKey(o => o.OrderId);

        this.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
            .WithRequired(oi => oi.Order)
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

        this.HasRequired(o => o.Institution)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(o => o.InstitutionId);

        this.Property(o => o.IsConfirmed)
            .IsRequired();

        this.Ignore(o => o.Id);
    }
}

public class OrderItemMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItem>
{
    public OrderItemMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("OrderItems", "prf");

        this.HasKey(oi => oi.OrderItemId);

        this.HasRequired(oi => oi.Order)
            .WithMany(oi => oi.OrderItems)
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderId);

        this.HasRequired(oi => oi.Proficiency)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.ProficiencyId);

        this.HasOptional(oi => oi.Enrolment)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.EnrolmentId);

        this.HasMany(oi => oi.OrderItemSets)
            .WithRequired(ois => ois.OrderItem)
            .HasForeignKey(ois => ois.OrderItemId);

        this.Property(oi => oi.DateCreated);

        this.Ignore(oi => oi.Id);
    }
}

public class OrderItemSetMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderItemSet>
{
    public OrderItemSetMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("OrderItemSets", "prf");

        this.HasKey(ois => ois.OrderItemSetId);

        this.HasRequired(ois => ois.OrderItem)
            .WithMany(ois => ois.OrderItemSets)
            .HasForeignKey(ois => ois.OrderItemId);

        this.Property(ois => ois.NumberOfSets);
        this.Property(ois => ois.Month);
    }
}
```

When I try to remove an OrderItemSet from the OrderItem's collection Entity Framework is trying to set the foreignkey in OrderItemSet as null instead of deleting the row even though the foreignkey is not nullable and therefore throwing an exception stating the foreignkey cannot be set to null.

```
this.OrderItemSets.Remove(orderItemSet);
```

I don't know what is wrong with my mapping to have Entity Framework think it should set the foreignkey to null instead of deleting the row.

Comment: Have you looked at the `WillCascadeOnDelete` option on foreign keys?

Comment: WillCascadeOnDelete will only delete child entities if the parent is being deleted. I am removing the child from the parent and therefore EF is removing the relationship between the two however since the foreignkey is not nullable it should delete the child as well and not set the foreignkey to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue as per Abbondanza's suggestion. First off create the key of the entity to contain the foreign key (this will force entity framework to delete the child item as it cannot exist without the foreign key):

```
public OrderItemSetMapping()
{
    ...

    this.HasKey(ois => new { ois.OrderItemSetId, ois.OrderItemId });

    ...
}
```

Entity Framework will now delete the entity if removed from the collection of the parent, however since OrderItemSetId is an Identity column this creates another issue where Entity Framework now wants to insert a value in that column when adding a new item to the parent collection (which will throw an exception). By specifying a DatabaseGenerationOption on this column the problem will be resolved:

```
public OrderItemSetMapping()
{
    ...

    this.Property(r => r.OrderItemSetId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not mark my answer as accepted? You basically used my answer and added something not directly related to your problem stated in the question. Not exactly nice, you know.

Comment: @Abbondanza I am sorry that you feel that way. I did give you the credit in the answer but the second part was definitely necessary for a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: May I suggest using HasAlternateKey instead? It achieves the same thing, without having to specify a multi-part key in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is an [identifying relationship](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373856(v=vs.100).aspx) between `OderItem` and `OrderItemSet`. From the section *Considerations for Identifying and Non-identifying Relationships* in the link provided above:

> Removing the relationship deletes the dependent object. Calling the Remove method on the EntityCollection marks both the relationship and the dependent object for deletion.

You should consider the same type of relation ship for `Order` and `OrderItem`.

The basic idea is that, for the model of `OrderItemSet`, you make the foreign key to `OrderItem` part of the `OrderItemSet`'s primary key, thus creating a *composite key*. Inside the mapping for `OrderItemSet` try to map the primary key like so:

```
public OrderItemSetMapping()
{
    ...

    this.HasKey(ois => new { ois.OrderItemSetId, ois.OrderItemId });

    ...
}
```

In case this [doesn't work with the fluent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398772/ef-composite-key-fluent-api), then try to create the mapping with attributes:

```
public class OrderItemSet
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("OrderItem"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public <YourKeyType> OrderItemId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public <YourKeyType> OrderItemSetId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I have removed the double relationship as stated but am still getting the foreignkey cannot be set to null error. this.HasMany(o => o.OrderItems)
                .WithRequired(o => o.Order)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.OrderId); and this.HasMany(oi => oi.OrderItemSets)
                .WithRequired(oi => oi.OrderItem)
                .HasForeignKey(oi => oi.OrderItemId);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just remove the child directly:

```
context.OrderItemSets.Remove(orderItemSet);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When you remove a child from a parent, you may want to add it to another parent, so it would be inappropriate for Entity Framework to delete the child automatically. You should do it yourself.